# How to provide additional flags only to the native cc compiler?

Tags: bazel, bazel-cpp

In our project team we applications for micro-controller targets with `arm-none-eabi-gcc`. For running our testrunner we compile using the native cc compiler.

In our project team most use a Linux os, but some us a windows os (for reasons). The issue we run into is that we use the C11 keyword `_Static_assert`. When compiling on Linux it works, but when compiling under windows we get the following error: `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Static_assert referenced in function {}`

This is due to the reason that the default MSVC compiler implements ANSI C89 which doesn't support the `_Static_assert` symbol. [MSVC - C standards support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=msvc-170#c-standards-support-1)

It also specifies that adding the `/std:c11` or `/std:c17` compiler options enable the support for `_Static_assert`.

We already have enabled `--enable_platform_specific_config` for other reasons.

Simply adding the `build:windows --copt="/std:c11"` to the `.bazelrc` solves the issue but also breaks the normal application build because `arm-none-eabi-gcc` compiler doesn't support the `/std:c11` compiler flag.

Question: How can i add the `/std:c11` compiler flag so that it only propagates to the native msvc compiler and not to the rest of my build targets?

Comment: `build:windows` suggests that you're running `bazel --config=windows`. Do you also use `--config=windows` in a build that runs `arm-none-eabi-gcc`?

Comment: I don't run `bazel --config=windows` explicitly. But it probably be implicit when building on windows

Comment: On Windows, do you run ARM gcc? Do you have some targets that are intended to be native and others which are intended to target ARM? Are the build rules for them marked somehow?

Comment: For our project we cross compile for an ARM micro-controller, using the `arm-none-eabi-gcc` compiler. So yes under window i invoke the arm gcc compiler to cross compile

Comment: Try `build:windows --host_copt="/std:c11"` in your `.bazelrc`?

Comment: To bad, same error: `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Static_assert referenced in function {}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248337/discussion-between-nick-lewycky-and-user2038134).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using MSVC for host builds (when building a tool that emits source code which is then `#include`'d, for example protocol buffer compiler) add `build:windows --host_copt="/std:c11"`. When using MSVC for test builds, add `test:windows --host_copt="/std:c11"`. Don't put it in `build:windows --copt` because that will apply even when running builds to the target.